# Create a middleware to add metadata to all outgoing DAPR messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, correlation, dapr

I would like to add a correlationId as metadata to all my outgoing DAPR messages in C#. I have created a middleware that I get CorrelationId from every time and then assign it to all outgoing Http requests, however I am unable to set correlationId to all outgoing DAPR messages. Can anyone help?

This is my CorrelationId middleware's invoke method

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ICorrelationIdGenerator correlationIdGenerator)
{
     var correlationId = correlationIdGenerator.Get() == null
                         ? Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
                         : correlationIdGenerator.Get();
     correlationIdGenerator.Set(correlationId);
     if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(Http.Headers.CORRELATION_ID))
     {
        context.Request.Headers.Add(Http.Headers.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId);
     }

     context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
     {
        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(Http.Headers.CORRELATION_ID))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(Http.Headers.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
     });
    await next(context);
}
```

and this is how everything is registered:

```
Services.AddScoped<ICorrelationIdGenerator, CorrelationIdGenerator>();
Services.AddDaprClient();
```

DaprClient is registered as Singleton when i look at the implementation.
At the moment I call correlationIdGenerator everytime I invoke Dapr's `PublishEventAsync` like so:

```
private readonly DaprClient _client;
private readonly ICorrelationIdGenerator _cid;
public MyClass(DaprClient client, ICorrelationIdGenerator cid)
{
    _client = client;
    _cid = cid;
}

var correlationId = _cid.Get();

var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { Http.Headers.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId }
};

await _client.PublishEventAsync("component", "my-topic", data, metadata: metadata);
```

So my goal is to inject metadata to all `PublishEventAsync` methods so I don't have to pass in the metadata for every call. Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

I am using `Dapr.AspNetCore v1.11.0` and `Dapr.Workflow v1.11.0`.

Comment: What sort of errors are you seeing? What happens when you try to debug it? You don't appear to be invoking the next middleware in the process.

Comment: I don't see any errors and I just forgot to add `next(context)` to the code piece. this is working. But I am trying to have a dynamic middleware that can set my metadata whenever i call `publisheventasync` so i don't have to pass in correlationid all the time

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about dapr, but the `PublishEventAsync` method may well not be using the same HttpContext as the incoming request